# How to turn off syntax highlighting in R-studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am very new to R-Studio. I was used to RGui, where there was no syntax highlight and the letters were very contrasty:

[image]

In R-Studio, the letters seem to be very dim, even the "black ones" doesn't seem as black as in RGui:

[image]

I don't have a clue how to change the colors (do you?) so I decided to turn off the syntax highlight completely. But I haven't found any way to do it. I tried `Tools / Global Options`, `Appearance` and `Code Editing`, but haven't found anything to change colors or turn off syntax highlighting.

Comment: If none of the themes in Rstudio suit you, you could try Eclipse+StatET or ESS where customization is better done. Have you tried another computer screen?

Comment: @Roman 1) and this Eclipse+StatET will work with the R console and plots as well? I need at least the functionality of RGui. 2) no i've only compared these on my laptop but that's where I need to work.

Comment: This is my workspace a few years ago. https://danganothererror.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/eclipse.jpg Graphics are bottom right (tab), but can be placed anywhere.

Comment: I don't have admin rights and can't test right now, but you could probably switch off syntax highlighting completely by editing the `r_highlight.html` file.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to turn off syntax highlighting completely. But it is possible to choose a different theme. Go to `Tools - Global Options - Appearance` and try the various settings for `Editor theme`. Maybe changing the font or font size could also improve readability.

Another option is to turn off syntax highlighting in a open file. In the lower right corner of the editor window, you should see `R Script` (or something else, if you are not currently editing an R Script) with two little arrows next to it:
[image: Change language for syntax highlighting]

When you click it, you can choose the language to use for syntax highlighting. If you pick `Text File`, there should be no highlighting at all. But you will have to redo this step whenever you load a file. At least, when you keep a file open in the editor and close RStudio, the setting will be kept when you start RStudio the next time.

Comment: Thanks Stibu. Unfortunatelly I don't like the default themes and I don't see any way to customize the themes, or is there? Thanks for the workaround with the `Text file`, but it would be annoying to do it for each new file.

Comment: I must say I start to be disappointed by R-studio. I supposed it to be user friendly and now I see it is not and look back to the old nice RGui. But I need the [autosave feature and it doesn't seem to be present in RGui](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28428038/684229).

Comment: I fear that the themes can not be customized. I have found an old [Question on the RStudio Support forum regarding this issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200671467-Customize-syntax-highlighting). There, they announce the themes, but the first sentence still let's me hope that they intend to do more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't turn off syntax highlighting. There is only option to show syntax highlighting in console input. But you can still change the colors :)

**Tools -> Global Options -> Appearance -> Editor Theme**

Comment: 1) There is no `Tools / Appearance` - you probably mean `Tools / Global Options / Appearance`? 2) I've already tried that, but none of those themes is what I want. And I didn't see any way to customize the themes.