# Autosave R sources in RGui

Tags: r, rgui

Is it possible to tell RGui to autosave the *.R sources, so that they don't get lost in case of system crash?

I miss this feature a lot since my system crashes now and then and I don't want to work with R-Studio or some other IDEs just because I need this feature... I like simplicity provided by RGui.